# WebBrowser Wrangling OR Efficient Regex.Replace of this HTML-escaped text

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am using a WebBrowser control in a Winforms app to act as an HTML WYSIWYG editor - trying to insert a link that looks like this:

```
<a href="RelativeUrl.aspx?Param1=true&Param2=butterfinger&Param3=somethingelse">
candy bar
</a>
```

...and that works fine, except the WebBrowser control is mangling the relative url with the "about:" prefix and replacing my ampersands:

```
<a href="about:RelativeUrl.aspx?Param1=true&amp;Param2=butterfinger&amp;Param3=somethingelse">
candy bar
```

I have been unable to find a way around this mutilation *(if you have one, PLEASE suggest it)*, so I'm resorting to regular expressions... and as the saying goes, now I have two problems.  I need to:

1. Remove the "about:" prefix in the URL and
2. Change the "&amp;" back to a simple ampersand.

The end result should read exactly like the first example - I can write a couple of regexes to do this, but I lack the regex-fu to know if I'm being anywhere near efficient - and I'd like to do it in a single step.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of using a (and more likely two) regex, could you simply try something along `someString.Replace("<a href=""about:", "<a href=""").Replace("&amp;", "&");`?

Comment: @Abecee That would work for the href="about:..." part, but I have to be careful to only replace the &amp; ONLY within the link's href.  It needs to stay like it is elsewhere in the HTML.

Comment: Going to get nasty. Proper retrieval would sure be the better option. Any chance to test a different control? Otherwise: Would you be sufficiently confident to string search for "&amp;Param" and to replace by "&Param"? If not, can you use positive lookahead? If so - and if you were willing to re-run until nothing is left to be replaced, you could start from `(<a href=".+?&)(?:amp;)(?=.+?">)`; see [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/fE6dB7/2) This would handle paragraphs in parallel, at least. Sorry no catch all in one go idea right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## NOTE

**This is a solution to a problem that *isn't* a problem.  I've learned that XHTML requires all attributes be HTML-escaped, and all the links work perfectly, so if you're running into this issue... be sure it's an issue.**

---

Here is what I've come up with - if no one has a better answer, I'll mark it as answer after a few days or so:

```
    public void FixLinks()
    {
        var input = editorWebBrowser.DocumentText;

        // this regex will match all href="about: ... " links
        const string hrefLinks = @"href\s?=\s?([""'])about:.*?\1";
        const RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline;

        // the key to doing it all in "one step" is calling ReplaceCruft delegate for every match
        var result = Regex.Replace(input, hrefLinks, ReplaceCruft, options);
        Html = result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Replaces "about:" and "amp;" text with an empty string in regular expression matches.
    ///     This corrects the WebControl munging the links when they're relative and ampersand escaping.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="match">
    ///     An href="about:..." link that needs un-munging.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    ///     A string without the about: prefix and & characters instead of &amp;
    /// </returns>
    private static string ReplaceCruft(Match match)
    {
        var input = match.Value;
        const string pattern = @"about:|amp;";
        const string replacement = "";
        const RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled;
        var result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement, options);
        return result;
    }
```

Again, please, if you know of a better way I'm all ears.

Also, this solution fixes the string but doesn't actually fix the problem.  When you assign the "un-munged" result back to the WebControl, it re-escapes the HTML characters and all you've gained is getting rid of the `about:` text.

Comment: You could use something like href=@Html.Raw(Json.Encode("RelativeUrl.aspx?Param1=true&Param2=butterfinger&Param3=somethingelse")). I've used this before with writing strings into JS calls, but I've never had link references munged up like this (maybe because I use Razor and MVC?)

Comment: It looks like my problem isn't really a problem.  XHTML requires that the ampersands in attributes be escaped, and the browser navigates the links just fine; I've been "fixing" a problem for two days that isn't a problem.